# VBA to List items (including folders) with specific word (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask if there's a way for VBA to list all files (including folders/subfolders) with word OLDIES-(whatever the text or number here)

```
Sub ListOLDIES()
Dim FSO As Object, FSOSubFolder As Object, FileName As String
Dim FSOFile As Object, objFolder As Object, RowNum As Integer
Dim ExtSplit As Variant, NameSplit As Variant
strDirectory = "C:\Desktop\"
RowNum = 1
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
For Each FSOSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    ListOLDIES
Next FSOSubFolder

For Each FSOFile In objFolder.Files
If InStr(FSOFile.path, "OLDIES") Then
ExtSplit = Split(FSOFile.path, ".")
NameSplit = Split(FSOFile.path, "\")
FileName = Left(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit)), _
           Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))) - Len(ExtSplit(UBound(ExtSplit))) - 1)
Flpath = Left(FSOFile.path, Len(FSOFile.path) - Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))))
ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 1) = FileName & ", " & Flpath & ", ." & ExtSplit(UBound(ExtSplit))
RowNum = RowNum + 1
End If
Next FSOFile
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Got an error "out of stack space" using that code.

Desired result;

| Name | Location | Extension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OLDIES-12345 | C:Desktop | Folder |
| OLDER-23456 | C:Desktop | .zip |
| OLDER-23457 | C:Desktop/OLDIES_12345 | .xlsx |

Thanks!

Comment: In which line of code did you get the error?

Comment: Remove the first loop... It just loops through and then calls itself recursively.  This will always produce a stack overflow as you describe.  `ListOLDIES`

Comment: @User51 that's not the solution. You need that recursively call in the loop to walk through the subfolders. You just need to make it use the subfolder each time. See my answer below.

Comment: @Peh Either remove the recursion or add a recursion base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your recursively run your procedure

```
For Each FSOSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    ListOLDIES
Next FSOSubFolder
```

but because you set the start folder to `strDirectory = "C:\Desktop\"` with every run of the procedure it starts running endless for `C:\Desktop\` and never goes into the subfolders.

If you put a `Debug.Print` into that loop

```
For Each FSOSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    Debug.Print FSOSubFolder.Path
    ListOLDIES
Next FSOSubFolder
```

You will see that it always prints the first subfolder and never goes into it. You can see that best when you run the code step by step using F8.

#### How to solve that issue?

So what you need to do is you need to set the start folder `strDirectory` to the subfolder when you recursively start your proceduer `ListOLDIES` again. Therefore we need to remove the `strDirectory = "C:\Desktop\"` add it as an argument.

```
Sub ListOLDIES(ByVal strDirectory As String)
```

And change the recourssive call to `ListOLDIES FSOSubFolder.Path`

If we now do a simple test using

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    ListOLDIES "C:\Desktop"
End Sub

Public Sub ListOLDIES(ByVal strDirectory As String)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
    
    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    For Each FSOSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        Debug.Print FSOSubFolder.Path
        ListOLDIES FSOSubFolder.Path
    Next FSOSubFolder
    
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    For Each FSOFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Print FSOFile.Path
    Next FSOFile
    
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

We get a list of all (sub)folders and files of `"C:\Desktop"`.

I used a test setup as follows:

```
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 1
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 2
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 2\OLDIES-12345
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 2\OLDIES-23456
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 2\OLDIES-23456\OLDIES-12345.zip
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 2\OLDIES-23456\OLDIES-23456.xml
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 3
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 3\OLDIES-12345.txt
C:\Desktop\Sub Folder 3\OLDIES-23456.txt
```

To maintain the `RowNum` counting over the entire recursive calls, you need to make that variable `Static`. And if you want to be able to reset it, add a parameter:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    ListOLDIES "C:\Desktop", True
End Sub

Public Sub ListOLDIES(ByVal strDirectory As String, Optional ByVal ResetRowNum As Boolean = False)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
    
    Static RowNum As Long
    If ResetRowNum Then RowNum = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' output sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' better use something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") to define a specific sheet name
    
    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    For Each FSOSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        InStr(1, FSOSubFolder.Name, "OLDIES", vbTextCompare)
            ' output folders with OLDIES
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = FSOSubFolder.Name
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = FSOSubFolder.ParentFolder.Path & "\"
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = "Folder"
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        End If
        ListOLDIES FSOSubFolder.Path
    Next FSOSubFolder
    
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    For Each FSOFile In objFolder.Files
        If InStr(1, FSOFile.Name, "OLDIES", vbTextCompare) Then
            ' output files with OLDIES
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = FSO.getBaseName(FSOFile)
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = FSOFile.ParentFolder.Path & "\"
            ws.Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = "." & FSO.getExtensionName(FSOFile)
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        End If
    Next FSOFile
    
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

So the output for my test setup would be:

[image: output]

Comment: FYI FSO has both `getExtensionName` and `getBaseName` methods so you could avoid the "manual" extraction of the filename elements.

Comment: Really appreciate this and as i try the code you provided to see if working - I put it on "thisWorkbook" then save then click play button. Nothing happens. Is that the right approach?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank's for pointing out. I adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: @mdashed I changed the output from the immediate window to the worksheet. Please see my edited code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - Thank you, it worked! I was thinking if i can add excluding folders to search?

Comment: @mdashed yes you can exclude folders by wrapping `ListOLDIES FSOSubFolder.Path` into an `If` statement where you check your criteria. Eg `If Not FSOSubFolder.Name = "Temp" Then` will exclude all folders that are named `Temp`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
Sub list_oldies()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    HostFolder = "C:\Users\salzerm.kontura\Desktop\Test\"
        
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder), 1
End Sub
    
Sub DoFolder(folder, RowNum As Integer)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim ExtSplit As Variant
    Dim NameSplit As Variant
    
    For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
        If InStr(SubFolder, "Oldies") Then
                ExtSplit = "Folder"
                NameSplit = Split(SubFolder, "\")
                Filename = Left(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit)), _
                           Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))) - 1)
                Flpath = Left(SubFolder, Len(SubFolder) - Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))))
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 1) = Filename
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 2) = Flpath
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 3) = ExtSplit
                RowNum = RowNum + 1
        End If
        
        DoFolder SubFolder, RowNum
    Next
    Dim file
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If file Like "*Oldies*.*" Then
                ExtSplit = Split(file, ".")
                NameSplit = Split(file, "\")
                Filename = Left(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit)), _
                           Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))) - Len(ExtSplit(UBound(ExtSplit))) - 1)
                Flpath = Left(file, Len(file) - Len(NameSplit(UBound(NameSplit))))
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 1) = Filename
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 2) = Flpath
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum, 3) = ExtSplit(UBound(ExtSplit))
                RowNum = RowNum + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add an explanation as to what changed and why it wasn't working to get full marks

Comment: This is actually works, however, can we do it if in main folder is also not case sensitive. under desktop if the name is "oldies" instead of Oldies it's not capturing

Comment: InStr(SubFolder, "Oldies") to InStr(lcase(SubFolder) , "oldies"). Also add lcase for the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It is fast, more compact and returns all you required, plus the initial returned array (in column D:D):

```
Sub list_oldies()
   Dim arrFoldFiles, strPath As String, strSearch As String
   Dim strExt As String, arrFin, i As Long, arrName, arrExt
   
   strSearch = "Oldies"
   strExt = "*" & strSearch & "*.*"
   strPath = "C:\Desktop\"
   
   arrFoldFiles = filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strPath & strExt & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
    ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrFoldFiles) + 1, 1 To 3)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFoldFiles)
        arrName = Split(arrFoldFiles(i), "\")
        arrExt = Split(arrName(UBound(arrName)), ".")
            arrFin(i + 1, 1) = arrExt(0)
        If UBound(arrExt) > 0 Then
             arrFin(i + 1, 3) = arrExt(1)
        Else
            arrFin(i + 1, 3) = "Folder"
        End If
        arrFin(i + 1, 2) = left(arrFoldFiles(i), InStrRev(arrFoldFiles(i), "\"))
    Next i
    'drop the arrays content:
    Range("A1:D1").value = Array("Name", "Location", "Extension", "All")
    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
    Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFoldFiles) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrFoldFiles)
    Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```